# PHP Sessions across a network

Tags: php, session

I have two PCs at home connected to my home network.

On my site when a user logs in I set a session cookie with their name & their ID e.g.:

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
$_SESSION["nwname"] = $firstname;
```

This obviously shows me they're logged in and thus can see their account.

I was under the impression that a session was set per machine, yet when I log in on one PC it automatically changes to the same login on the other PC in the network.

Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sessions aren't simply unique per machine, but per browser and should terminate when the browser is closed.... check the session id in the cookie on each machine, and you'll probably see that they're not the same

Comment: Depends on your config but its more likely that your code has bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have logged in on both computers at some point, or cookies are being shared somehow.

A PHP session just stores the SESSION id as a cookie on your computer.

Comment: I cleared cookies on both and ok now but I'm still intrigued how one machine knew what the other was doing.